# Laravel route works, but returns 404 status

Tags: php, xml, laravel, nginx, http-status-code-404

I have created a dynamic sitemap.xml route with laravel, that returns a xml response.

The route **works on the browser**, but it returns a **404 status**.

**This is the only route that returns a 404 status**

**These are the headers**:

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →232
Content-Type →text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Date →Thu, 24 Mar 2016 09:44:35 GMT
Server →nginx/1.9.12
```

**This is the route**:

```
Route::get('sitemap.xml', ['as' => 'sitemap.index', 'uses' => 'SitemapController@index']);
```

**This is the controller response**:

```
    $response = response()->view('sitemaps.index', [
        'last'    => $data,
        'modules' => $modules,
        'app'     => $app,
    ])->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    $response->header('Content-Length',strlen($response->getOriginalContent()));

    return $response;
```

**The view**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
@foreach($modules as $module)
    <sitemap>
        <loc>{{ url('sitemap-' . $module . '.xml') }}</loc>
        <lastmod>{{ $last[$module]['updated_at'] or date('Y').'-01-01'}}</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
@endforeach
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Nginx problem.

I added this code on my config file and now it works:

```
location = /sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

And I removed the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from the response.